# MySQL: Join Statements: Why doesn't this work?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, workbench

Well, I'm working on an assignment, and we're using JOIN ... ON statements, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but nothing appears when I run my SQL code into the database.

EDIT:
Not receiving any errors. The code runs without flaw.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is an INNER JOIN the correct kind of join for this situation?? (Join statement can be found at the end of the code...)

```
 SELECT orders.order_ID as 'Order ID'
      , orders.order_date as 'Order Date'
  , CONCAT(customers.customer_first_name, ' ', customers.customer_last_name) as 'Customer'
   , customers.customer_city as 'City'
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers
  ON orders.customer_ID = customers.customer_ID
 WHERE customer.customer_state = 'OH'
 ORDER BY orders
```

All the SQL ...

```
/* Sierra McGivney - Lab5 - Additions */

/*Drop Tables*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order_details;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS items;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS artists;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees;

/*create tables*/
CREATE TABLE customers
(
 customer_id      INT,
 customer_first_name  VARCHAR(20),
 customer_last_name  VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
 customer_address   VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
 customer_city     VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
 customer_state    CHAR(2)     NOT NULL,
 customer_zip     CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
 customer_phone    CHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
 customer_fax     CHAR(10),
 CONSTRAINT customers_pk 
 PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE artists
(
 artist_id      INT       NOT NULL,
 artist_name  VARCHAR(30),
 CONSTRAINT artist_pk 
 PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE items
(
 item_id    INT       NOT NULL,
 title     VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
 artist_id   INT   NOT NULL,
 unit_price  DECIMAL(9,2)  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT items_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
 CONSTRAINT items_fk_artists
  FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artists (artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE employees
(
 employee_id     INT        NOT NULL,
 last_name      VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
 first_name     VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
  manager_id     INT,
CONSTRAINT employees_pk 
 PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
CONSTRAINT emp_fk_mgr FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees(employee_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
 order_id     INT     NOT NULL,
 customer_id    INT     NOT NULL,
 order_date    DATE    NOT NULL,
 shipped_date   DATE,
 employee_id    INT,
 CONSTRAINT orders_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
 CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
CONSTRAINT orders_fk_employees
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE order_details
(
 order_id   INT      NOT NULL,
 item_id    INT      NOT NULL,
 order_qty   INT      NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT order_details_pk 
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id, item_id),
 CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_orders
  FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
  REFERENCES orders (order_id),
 CONSTRAINT order_details_fk_items
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
  REFERENCES items (item_id)
);

/*insert rows into tables*/
INSERT INTO customers VALUES 
(1,'Korah','Blanca','1555 W Lane Ave','Columbus','OH','43221','6145554435','6145553928'),
(2,'Yash','Randall','11 E Rancho Madera Rd','Madison','WI','53707','2095551205','2095552262'),
(3,'Johnathon','Millerton','60 Madison Ave','New York','NY','10010','2125554800',NULL),
(4,'Mikayla','Davis','2021 K Street Nw','Washington','DC','20006','2025555561',NULL),
(5,'Kendall','Mayte','4775 E Miami River Rd','Cleves','OH','45002','5135553043',NULL),
(6,'Kaitlin','Hostlery','3250 Spring Grove Ave','Cincinnati','OH','45225','8005551957','8005552826'),
(7,'Derek','Chaddick','9022 E Merchant Wy','Fairfield','IA','52556','5155556130',NULL),
(8,'Deborah','Davis','415 E Olive Ave','Fresno','CA','93728','5595558060',NULL),
(9,'Karina','Lacy','882 W Easton Wy','Los Angeles','CA','90084','8005557000',NULL),
(10,'Kurt','Nickalus','28210N Avenue Stanford','Valencia','CA','91355','8055550584','055556689'),
(11,'Kelsey','Eulalia','7833 N Ridge Rd','Sacramento','CA','95887','2095557500','2095551302'),
(12,'Anders','Rohansen','12345 E 67th Ave NW','Takoma Park','MD','24512','3385556772',NULL),
(13,'Thalia','Neftaly','2508 W Shaw Ave','Fresno','CA','93711','5595556245',NULL),
(14,'Gonzalo','Keeton','12 Daniel Road','Fairfield','NJ','07004','2015559742',NULL),
(15,'Ania','Irvin','1099 N Farcourt St','Orange','CA','92807','7145559000',NULL),
(16,'Dakota','Baylee','1033 NSycamore Ave.','Los Angeles','CA','90038','2135554322',NULL),
(17,'Samuel','Jacobsen','3433 E Widget Ave','Palo Alto','CA','92711','4155553434',NULL),
(18,'Justin','Javen','828 S Broadway','Tarrytown','NY','10591','8005550037',NULL),
(19,'Kyle','Marissa','789 E Mercy Ave','Phoenix','AZ','85038','9475553900',NULL),
(20,'Erick','Kaleigh','Five Lakepointe Plaza, Ste 500','Charlotte','NC','28217','7045553500',NULL),
(21,'Marvin','Quintin','2677 Industrial Circle Dr','Columbus','OH','43260','6145558600','6145557580'),
(22,'Rashad','Holbrooke','3467 W Shaw Ave #103','Fresno','CA','93711','5595558625','5595558495'),
(23,'Trisha','Anum','627 Aviation Way','Manhatttan Beach','CA','90266','3105552732',NULL),
(24,'Julian','Carson','372 San Quentin','San Francisco','CA','94161','6175550700',NULL),
(25,'Kirsten','Story','2401 Wisconsin Ave NW','Washington','DC','20559','2065559115',NULL);

INSERT INTO artists(artist_id,artist_name) VALUES 
(10,'Umani'),
(11,'The Ubernerds'),
(12,'No Rest For The Weary'),
(13,'Burt Ruggles'),
(14,'Sewed the Vest Pocket'),
(15,'Jess & Odie'),
(16,'Onn & Onn');

INSERT INTO items (item_id,title,artist_id,unit_price) VALUES 
(1,'Umami In Concert',10,17.95),
(2,'Race Car Sounds',11,13),
(3,'No Rest For The Weary',12,16.95),
(4,'More Songs About Structures and Comestibles',12,17.95),
(5,'On The Road With Burt Ruggles',13,17.5),
(6,'No Fixed Address',14,16.95),
(7,'Rude Noises',15,13),
(8,'Burt Ruggles: An Intimate Portrait',13,17.95),
(9,'Zone Out With Umami',10,16.95),
(10,'Etcetera',16,17);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES 
(1,'Smith','Cindy',null),
(2,'Jones','Elmer',1),
(3,'Simonian','Ralph',2),
(9,'Locario','Paulo',1),
(8,'Leary','Rhea',9),
(4,'Hernandez','Olivia',9),
(5,'Aaronsen','Robert',4),
(6,'Watson','Denise',8),
(7,'Hardy','Thomas',2);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(19,1,'2012-10-23','2012-10-28',6),
(29,8,'2012-11-05','2012-11-11',6),
(32,11,'2012-11-10','2012-11-13',NULL),
(45,2,'2012-11-25','2012-11-30',NULL),
(70,10,'2012-12-28','2013-01-07',5),
(89,22,'2013-01-20','2013-01-22',7),
(97,20,'2013-01-29','2013-02-02',5),
(118,3,'2013-02-24','2013-02-28',7),
(144,17,'2013-03-21','2013-03-29',NULL),
(158,9,'2013-04-04','2013-04-20',NULL),
(165,14,'2013-04-11','2013-04-13',NULL),
(180,24,'2013-04-25','2013-05-30',NULL),
(231,15,'2013-06-14','2013-06-22',NULL),
(242,23,'2013-06-24','2013-07-06',3),
(264,9,'2013-07-15','2013-07-18',6),
(298,18,'2013-08-18','2013-09-22',3),
(321,2,'2013-09-09','2013-10-05',6),
(381,7,'2013-11-08','2013-11-16',7),
(413,17,'2013-12-05','2014-01-11',7),
(442,5,'2013-12-28','2014-01-03',5),
(479,1,'2014-01-30','2014-03-03',3),
(491,16,'2014-02-08','2014-02-14',5),
(523,3,'2014-03-07','2014-03-15',3),
(548,2,'2014-03-22','2014-04-18',NULL),
(550,17,'2014-03-23','2014-04-03',NULL),
(601,16,'2014-04-21','2014-04-27',NULL),
(607,20,'2014-04-25','2014-05-04',NULL),
(624,2,'2014-05-04','2014-05-09',NULL),
(627,17,'2014-05-05','2014-05-10',NULL),
(630,20,'2014-05-08','2014-05-18',7),
(651,12,'2014-05-19','2014-06-02',7),
(658,12,'2014-05-23','2014-06-02',7),
(687,17,'2014-06-05','2014-06-08',NULL),
(693,9,'2014-06-07','2014-06-19',NULL),
(703,19,'2014-06-12','2014-06-19',7),
(778,13,'2014-07-12','2014-07-21',7),
(796,17,'2014-07-19','2014-07-26',5),
(800,19,'2014-07-21','2014-07-28',NULL),
(802,2,'2014-07-21','2014-07-31',NULL),
(824,1,'2014-08-01',NULL,NULL),
(827,18,'2014-08-02',NULL,NULL),
(829,9,'2014-08-02',NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO order_details VALUES 
(381,1,1),
(601,9,1),
(442,1,1),
(523,9,1),
(630,5,1),
(778,1,1),
(693,10,1),
(118,1,1),
(264,7,1),
(607,10,1),
(624,7,1),
(658,1,1),
(800,5,1),
(158,3,1),
(321,10,1),
(687,6,1),
(827,6,1),
(144,3,1),
(479,1,2),
(630,6,2),
(796,5,1),
(97,4,1),
(601,5,1),
(800,1,1),
(29,10,1),
(70,1,1),
(165,4,1),
(180,4,1),
(231,10,1),
(413,10,1),
(491,6,1),
(607,3,1),
(651,3,1),
(703,4,1),
(802,3,1),
(824,7,2),
(829,1,1),
(550,4,1),
(796,7,1),
(693,6,1),
(29,3,1),
(32,7,1),
(242,1,1),
(298,1,1),
(479,4,1),
(548,9,1),
(627,9,1),
(778,3,1),
(19,5,1),
(89,4,1),
(242,6,1),
(264,4,1),
(550,1,1),
(693,7,3),
(824,3,1),
(829,5,1),
(829,9,1);

/*Exercise One*/
SELECT customer_last_name as 'Last Name', customer_first_name as 'First Name', customer_phone as 'Phone'
FROM customers
ORDER BY customer_last_name, customer_first_name, customer_phone;

/*Exercise Two*/
SELECT 
    CONCAT(customer_first_name, ' ' , customer_last_name) as 'Customer', customer_phone as 'Phone'
FROM customers
WHERE customer_state IN ('NY','NJ','DC')
ORDER BY customer_phone;

/*Exercise Three*/
SELECT DISTINCT customer_city as 'Cities'
FROM customers
ORDER BY customer_city DESC;

/*Exercise Four*/
SELECT title as "Title", unit_price as 'Original', ROUND((unit_price - (unit_price * .25)), 2) as "Sale"
FROM items
ORDER BY unit_price ASC;

/*Exercise Five*/
SELECT 
    CONCAT(customer_first_name, ' ' , customer_last_name) as 'Customer', customer_city as "City"
FROM customers
WHERE customer_zip LIKE '4%'
ORDER BY customer_city;

/*Exercise Six*/
SELECT order_id as "Order ID", DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M-%d-%Y') as "Order Date"
FROM orders
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') IN ('March', 'April', 'May') AND DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y') IN ('2014') 
ORDER BY order_date;

/*Exercise Seven*/
SELECT order_id as "Order ID", DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%d-%y') as "Ordered"
FROM orders
WHERE order_date BETWEEN '14-05-01' AND '14-05-31'
ORDER BY order_date;

/*Exercise Eight*/
SELECT order_ID as 'Order ID', customer_id as 'Customer ID', DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) as 'Difference'
FROM orders
WHERE DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) >= 15
ORDER BY customer_id;

/*Exercise Nine*/
SELECT order_id as 'Order ID', customer_id as 'Customer ID', DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%d-%y') as 'Date Ordered'
FROM orders
WHERE shipped_date IS NULL
ORDER BY order_date DESC;

/*Exercise Ten*/
SELECT order_id as 'Order ID', DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%d-%y') as 'Date Ordered', 
    DATE_FORMAT(shipped_date, '%m-%d-%y') as 'Date Shipped', DAYNAME(shipped_date) as 'Order Day'
FROM orders
WHERE DAYNAME(shipped_date) = 'Sunday' OR DAYNAME(shipped_date) = 'Saturday'
ORDER BY DAYNAME(shipped_date);

/*Exercise Eleven*/
SELECT customer_last_name as 'Last Name', customer_phone as 'Phone', customer_fax as 'Fax'
FROM customers
WHERE customer_fax IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY customer_fax;

/*Exercise Twelve*/
INSERT items VALUES
(11,'Ode To My ERD',15,12.95);

SELECT item_id as 'Item ID', title as 'Title', artist_id as 'Artist ID', unit_price as 'Unit Price'
FROM items 
WHERE item_id >10;

/*Exercise Thirteen*/
UPDATE items
SET unit_price = 7.95
WHERE item_id = 11;

SELECT item_id as 'Item ID', title as 'Title', artist_id as 'Artist ID', unit_price as 'Unit Price'
FROM items 
WHERE item_id > 10;

/*Exercise Fourteen*/
DELETE FROM items
WHERE item_id > 10;
/*If it works, this should leave us with only TWO displays of an item with Item ID of 11.*/
SELECT item_id as 'Item ID', title as 'Title', artist_id as 'Artist ID', unit_price as 'Unit Price'
FROM items 
WHERE item_id > 10;

/*Exercise Fifteen*/
SELECT 
    CONCAT(customer_last_name, ', ', customer_first_name) as 'Customer',
    CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING(customer_phone, 1, 3) , ')' , 
               SUBSTRING(customer_phone, 4, 3) , '-' ,
               SUBSTRING(customer_phone, 7, 4)) as 'Phone'
FROM customers
ORDER BY CONCAT(customer_last_name, ', ', customer_first_name); 

/*Week Five Lab*/
SELECT orders.order_ID as 'Order ID', orders.order_date as 'Order Date',  
    CONCAT(customers.customer_first_name, ' ', customers.customer_last_name) as 'Customer', customers.customer_city as 'City'
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers
ON orders.customer_ID = customers.customer_ID
WHERE customer.customer_state = 'OH'
ORDER BY orders.order_date DESC;
```

Comment: Query looks alright. Do you have any records in customer table with customer_state = 'OH'?

Comment: have you error ?  or the result is not what you aspected .. show sample data...

Comment: I thought it looked good too. I do have records with the state being 'OH'... I'll add them in a moment to show...let me know if you want the whole code...because it doesn't give any errors when I run it, it's just that nothing shows for that segment of my code.

Comment: Posted whole code if it helps.

Comment: Wow! ***That*** is an example of a well posed question! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much (Perl Dog)! I've been trying to work on that. I've had some badly worded ones before!!   Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should

```
WHERE customer.customer_state = 'OH'
```

be

```
WHERE customers.customer_state = 'OH'
```

?

Here's a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c86c/1

(notice the s on customers)

Comment: Oh my goodness!! Thank you so much. That's a silly thing of me to have done.

Comment: i live near redmond and if you get the newer versions of SQL Server, you don't have to mess w stuff like this, its smart enough to figure it out. You get what you pay for with open source software I guess!

Answer (score 2):

I think John found the problem. It surprises me that your SQL client did not give an error.

In the future, you should alias your tables, like below. It will make your query easier to read and errors like this easier to spot.

```
/*Week Five Lab*/
SELECT o.order_ID as 'Order ID', o.order_date as 'Order Date',  
    CONCAT(c.customer_first_name, ' ', c.customer_last_name) as 'Customer', c.customer_city as 'City'
FROM Orders o
   JOIN Customers c
      ON o.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
WHERE c.customer_state = 'OH'
ORDER BY o.order_date DESC;
```

Comment: YMMV, but I don't think single-character aliases makes this easier to read…

Comment: Fair point. I prefer them to whole-table names though. Perhaps short aliases are best, e.g. cust, ord.

Comment: Aliases are mostly redundant on columns that have the table-name as a prefix.

Comment: It's good to know, but I'll have to agree that until I get the hang of this I might want to keep the whole table names! But it is something I'd like to keep in mind for future's sake. Thanks for the help!